# Retryable within transaction

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-retry

I am experiencing a RollbackException being thrown when closing a transaction. For some context, during this transactional there is a retry attempt which is successful.

The structure is like below but not exact for simplicity..

```
@Transactional
void parentLevel(){
    childLevel() 
}


@Retryable
@Transactional
void childLevel(){
}
```

I am assuming that I should simply place the @Retryable on the parent level method as I am playing with fire by retrying within a transactional (I assume this is the issue) but this would require major amounts of changes (concurrency occurs, etc) so I am trying to see if there is an alternative before beginning these changes.

Comment: what is the problem that you have ? What is exactly the issue that you get ?

Comment: I just went with the re-factoring.. retrying the entire process instead of at the database level. 

Previously, I could see the retry occurring and resolving. 
But when the parent level transactional closes (end of process), the exception that occurred during the retry trickled up and threw at the parent transactional. So everything rolled back. @AndreiLisa